# Non angular landing page with authentification and angular app routing / redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, routes

I searched a lot in here, and i couldnt find an answer to the questions I ask myself. Here is the thing :

On one side , I want to have a static landing page (with login/sign up form ), and on the other side, I have an angular app that handles all the things related to the authenticated user. It's like that because my app is kind of "private", so users that cant register or login do not have to load the entire angular app and can't go further than the landing.

On the landing page, the login request  hits on my API, and with the given credentials I store the user access token in the local storage, which allows him to do all the future requests inside the angular app.

What I want to do is to have the same URL for both the landing and the angular app. Let's say the base url is www.myproject.com, when I go to this url, depending on if i'm logged or not, i want to be redirected to the landing page or the angular app. It's also based on a "Remember me" checkbox.

So how do I do to share www.myproject.com between the landing and the angular app, depending on the user state ( logged or not ) ? Is it some kind of server routing ? Or can I achieved this with angular ui-router ?

It's only a matter of fanciness, i could also have urls like www.myproject.com for the landing, and www.myproject.com/app for the angular app, but the real problem here is how to do the logged/not logged based routing. If it simpler to explain with two differents urls, I'm interested too.

Thank you for your answers, i feel really lost here !

**EDIT**
Since ALL the requests inside the angular app need the access token, what if I catch 401 error that i might get from oAuth when entering the angular app, with an http interceptor ? Could I use this to redirect to my external landing page file ?

I don't really need the share of the root url between the landing and the app, all I want to know is : is catching 401 code a good way to redirect to the landing/login page ?